# Reordering parentheses using associative property in Racket

Tags: racket, parentheses, associativity

I am having trouble implementing a function that given something like this:

```
'((+(d + e) + f) + (a + (a + c))
```

Returns this:

```
'(d + (e + (f + (a + (a + c)))))
```

Now the catch is that I have to use associativity to get the answer so I only want to use this property:

```
'((a + b) + c) = '(a + (b + c))
```

To get the correct output. I know how to implement the function for this case:

```
'((a + b) + c) -> '(a + (b + c))
```

However I cannot seem to figure out how to implement it for the first case above (or any other case larger than three items). I am not looking for answers only some guidance. If you would like to see code snippets let me know and I can post some. Also, I created a function that stripped the '+ from the list to make it easier to process.

I think this defines the grammar:

```
var ::=  a | b | c | d | e | f | g
fpip ::= var | (fpip + fpip)
```

Where a valid fpip can be:

```
fpip = '((a + b) + c)
```

or

```
fpip = '((a + b) + (c + d))
```

and at it's most atomic level:

```
fpip = '(a + b)
```

edit: yes the initial '+ should be erased. Regardless of how many plus signs there are in the initial input there should only be (amount-of-vars - 1) '+  in the output. For example:

```
'(+ + + + (a + b) + + c) -> '(a + (b + c)
```

Comment: Do you have a grammar for your input syntax?

Comment: I think I defined the grammar however correct me if I did not.

Comment: In your example you have `(+(d + e) ...)`. Should the first `+` be erased?

Comment: `(+ + + + (a + b) + + c)` is not a valid `fpip`. The whole point of having a grammar is to be strict so you should **not** make that one work.

Comment: @Sylwester you're right. The initial '+ was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are the cases to consider. Let's call the the recursive rewriter REWRITE.

```
var                               -> var
(var + var)                       -> (var + var)
(var + (fip1 + fpip2))            -> (var + (REWRITE (fip1 + fpip2))
((fip1 + fpip2) + var)            -> (REWRITE (fip1 + (fip2 + var))
((fip1 + fpip2) + (fip3 + fpip4)) -> (REWRITE (fip1 + (fip2 + (fip3 + fip4))))
```