# Rearranging list into left-normal form in Racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket, normalization, recursive-descent

I was going to post this to the codereview stackexchange but I saw that you should only post working code. I asked this question earlier: [Reordering parentheses using associative property in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864511/reordering-parentheses-using-associative-property-in-racket)

In case you don't check the link basically I want to rearrrange a list of symbols so that this:

```
'((a + b) + c) -> '(a + (b + c))
```

or this:

```
'((a + b) + (c + d)) -> '(a + (b + (c + d)))
```

This is the code I've written so far:

```
(define (check? expr)
  (display expr)
  (newline)
  (cond ((null? expr) -1)
        ((and (atom? (car expr)) (atom? (cadr expr))) 0) ;case 0
        ((and (atom? (car expr)) (list? (cadr expr))) 1) ;case 1
        ((and (list? (car expr)) (null? (cdr expr))) (check? (car expr))) ;nested expression for example '((a b))
        ((and (list? (car expr)) (atom? (cadr expr))) 2) ;case 2
        ((and (list? (car expr)) (list? (cadr expr))) 3) ;case 3
        (else -1)))


(define (rewrite x)
  (display (check? x))
  (newline)
  (cond ((null? x))
        ((atom? x) x)
        ((= 0 (check? x))   x) ;case 0 is '(a + b)
        ((= 1 (check? x)) (cons (car x) (rewrite (cdr x)))) ;case 1 is '(a +  (b + c))
        ((= 2 (check? x)) (rewrite (list (caar x) (cons (cadar x) (cdr x))))) ;case 2 is ((b + c) + a)
        ((= 3 (check? x)) (rewrite ((list (caar x) (cons (cadar x) (cdr x))))))));case 3 is ((a + b) + (c + d))


;(rewrite '(((d c) b) a))
(rewrite '(a b))
(rewrite '(a (b c)))
(rewrite '((a b) (c d)))
```

Am I on the right track? If not does anyone have any pointers? Am I creating the lists wrong? If you need any more information let me know or if I should comment the code better also let me know.

In case you don't check the earlier question, this is the answer I got (which was very helpful):

```
var                               -> var
(var + var)                       -> (var + var)
(var + (fip1 + fpip2))            -> (var + (REWRITE (fip1 + fpip2))
((fip1 + fpip2) + var)            -> (REWRITE (fip1 + (fip2 + var))
((fip1 + fpip2) + (fip3 + fpip4)) -> (REWRITE (fip1 + (fip2 + (fip3 + fip4))))
```

Comment: Why not flatten the list first, then rebuild the flattened list as right-associative? Ie. going from `'((a + b) + (c + d))` --> `'(a + b + c + d)` --> `'(a + (b + (c + d)))`.

Comment: I'm studying for a test and the prompt on this practice test explicitly says not to do it that way. Anyway, I think I'd have a better handle on recursion if I could do it using the associative property.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `match`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the grammar you have defined for your syntax:

```
var  ::=  a | b | c | d | e | f | g
fpip ::=  var | (fpip + fpip)
```

As such, we can start by defining predicates that test whether a given expression is valid or not, using the rules set above:

```
(define (var? e)
  (member e '(a b c d e f g)))

(define (fpip? e)
  (cond
    ((var? e) #t)
    ((or (not (pair? e))
         (null? e)
         (null? (cdr e))
         (null? (cddr e))
         (not (null? (cdddr e))))
     #f)
    (else (and (fpip? (car e))
               (equal? (cadr e) '+)
               (fpip? (caddr e))))))
```

Now we can say, for example:

```
> (fpip? 'a)
#t
> (fpip? '((a + b) + c))
#t
> (fpip? '((+(d + e) + f) + (a + (a + c))))
#f
```

With that in place, `rewrite` can be written as the right-associative form of an expression, if the expression is valid fpip, and `#f` otherwise:

```
(define (rewrite e)
  (if (not (fpip? e))
      #f
      (rewrite-fpip e)))
```

Next, we will define `rewrite-fpip` to be a procedure that accepts and transforms any *valid* fpip, as follows:

```
(define (rewrite-fpip e)
  (cond
    ((not (pair? e)) e)                                         ;; var
    ((not (pair? (car e)))
     (list (car e) '+ (rewrite-fpip (caddr e))))                ;; (var + fpip)
    (else
     (rewrite-fpip                                              ;; (fpip + fpip)
      (list (caar e) '+ (list (caddar e) '+ (caddr e)))))))
```

Thus we can have:

```
> (rewrite 'a)
'a
> (rewrite '((a + b) + c))
'(a + (b + c))
> (rewrite '((a + b) + (c + d)))
'(a + (b + (c + d)))
> (rewrite '(((d + e) + f) + (a + (a + c))))
'(d + (e + (f + (a + (a + c)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

That they tell you not to use the *flattening* in your solution doesn't mean you can't use the flattening in the *derivation* of your solution.

Writing in an imaginary pattern-matching equational pseudocode (because it is much shorter and visually apparent, i.e. easier to follow),

```lisp
flatten a         = flatten2 a []               ; [] is "an empty list"
flatten2 (a+b) z  = flatten2 a (flatten2 b z)   ; if it matches (a+b)
flatten2 a     [] = a                           ; if it doesn't, and the 2nd is []
flatten2 a     b  = a + b                       ; same, and the 2nd arg is not []
```

Oh wait, I'm *not* flattening it here, I *am* building the normalized sum expressions here!

The only problem with this approach is the needless check for `[]` repeated over and over when we *know* it will only ever be true *once* -- it is *we* who write this code after all.

Fusing this knowledge in, we get

```lisp
normalize  a   = down a             ; turn EXPR ::= ATOM | EXPR + EXPR
down (a + b)   = up a (down b)
down a         = a                  ; into NormExpr ::= ATOM | ATOM + NormExpr
up   (a + b) z = up a (up b z)
up   a       b = a + b
```

Now all's left is to code this up in regular Scheme. Scheme also has the advantage that the test can be much simplified to just

```lisp
(define (is-sum? a+b) (pair? a+b))
```

*edit:* The final function from the other answer in the same pseudocode is:

```lisp
rewrite ((a + b) + c) = rewrite (a + (b + c))     ; rotate right!
rewrite (a + b)       = a + rewrite b             ; go in, if the first rule didn't match
rewrite a             = a                         ; stop, if the first two didn't match
```

It rearranges the `+` nodes' tree structure *before* starting the work<sup>1</sup>, whereas the solution in this answer follows the input structure *while* transforming it.  As the result, thanks to the nested recursion the run time stack will only be as deep as the input structure, whereas with `rewrite` it will always be *n* levels deep at the deepest point, when the list is fully linearized on the stack (in the second rule), just before the sums are assembled on the way back up.

But the first rule in `rewrite` is tail recursive, and the second is [tail recursive modulo `cons`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons), so `rewrite` can be rewritten in a tail-recursive style as a whole, with few standard modifications. Which is definitely a plus.

On the other hand this new code will have to surgically modify (i.e. mutate) the `+` nodes (see the Wikipedia article linked above, for details), so you'll have to choose your implementation of this data type accordingly. If you use lists, this means using `set-car!` and/or `set-cdr!`; otherwise you can implement them as [Racket's `#:mutable` structures](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html#%28tech._mutator%29). When the result is built, you could convert it to a regular list with an additional *O(n)* traversal, if needed.

---

<sup>1</sup> reminiscent of [the old `gopher` trick](http://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html) from John McCarthy, burrowing into the input structure, with reified continuations.